# Dock panel not see correct in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I was download the  dock panel html project from [there](http://www.htmldockfloat.com/index.htm) and 
you see demo from [there](http://www.htmldockfloat.com/demo/JavaScriptDockFloatSimpleDemo.html)
The  structure of dock panel in downloaded html page not show in Google Chrome
and my Google chrome version is 37.0.2062.124.
please help me.please give your suggestion.

Comment: This question should be obliterated. Why cant we close questions with bounty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Chrome Versión 38.0.2125.104 m and it works fine for me (the online demo)  and I must admit the panel is really nice I really like it. All divs and funtions works for me, all links buttons etc so I believe you will have to update your Chrome version or try the follow:

EDIT

I downloaded the package and you are right, the  downloaded version is not working. To make it easier use WebZip or another tool to download a complete copy of the online demo and it will save a good copy of the panel and it will work for you, there must be something wrong in the downloaded file something is missing seems like

Good Look with the project

Comment: The downloaded file JS is coded you must purchase a license to use it

Comment: I decoded the encoded file of the downloaded version and now it works fine. I cannot tell you how to decode it but maybe jsbeautifier DOT ORG can do it

Comment: I download and save web page then change my jquery and it's work.